# how to run the emulator from the command line on ubuntu11.10

Tags: android, android-emulator, ubuntu-11.10

I am new to android building, so please excuse me if my question is 
too easy :)

My build process seemed to be successful, however the "emulator" command fails with 
this error:

```
emulator: ERROR: bad workspace: cannot find prebuilt kernel in: /aosp/ 
prebuilt/android-arm/kernel/kernel-qemu-armv7 .
```

I have no idea why I am getting this error.

please help me.

Comment: how to check that i have created AVD's or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//here andy_1.6 is my avd name.

```
padmakumar@padmakumar-desktop:~$ emulator -avd andy_1.6
```

//creating avd using cmd

```
 padmakumar@padmakumar-desktop:~$ android create avd -n testavd
```

[how to create avd](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/managing-avds.html)

Comment: yeah i have created the AVD's

Answer (score 0):

Old post but the problem is that cyanogenmod changed some stuff (including the location of prebuilt kernel), and when you do a source build/envsetup.sh this should fix it but it doesn't, anyway here's how you fix it:

```
emulator -kernel prebuilt/android-arm/kernel/kernel-qemu-armv7
```

Answer (score 0):

In 4.3, the path has changed, try this:

```
    emulator -kernel /Volumes/android/prebuilts/qemu-kernel/arm/kernel-qemu-armv7
```

In the future, if you would like to get an insight in terms of how does the emulator pick the default kernel, try:

```
    emulator -verbose
```

then look for kernel.path to find out.